# How does one pass vars into nested loops in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, input

I am attempting to write a small PowerShell script to clean up files names from some log dumps, but I seem to be stuck... I have logs dumped from various sources, and the file names seem to be getting garbled up.

I am looking to for name the names of files like so... " Source - Service.log "

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -Path ~/Desktop/New | ForEach-Object {
    while ([string]($_.Name) -notmatch "^[a-z].*" -or [string]($_.Name) -notmatch "^[A-Z].*") {
        Rename-Item -NewName { [string]($_.Name).Substring(1) }
    }
    Write-Host $_.Name
}
```

The output seems to be erroring out.

```
Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is
specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be
evaluated without input.
At line:8 char:30
+         Rename-Item -NewName { $File.Substring(1) }
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Rename-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentNoInput,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

The Idea is to check the filename to to see if it is a character, and if not remove it, to remove ". - / and whitespace"

The orginal files I am running against are like this:

```
1. source - data (1).log
100. - source - Data.log
(1)  Source - data.log
source - data.log
<space><space> source - data.log
```

and  the result I am looking for from the above is: I am not concerned about the duplicates file names as source and data change day to day and the folder is cleared regularly...

```
source - data (1).log
source - Data.log
Source - data.log
source - data.log
source - data.log
```

Can someone tell me how to get past this error?

Comment: You're getting that error, b/c `Rename-Item -NewName {...}` expects input from the pipeline, which you don't provide. Do either `$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {...}` or `Rename-Item $_.FullName (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to delete leading non-alpha characters, you can simplify what you're doing:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path ~\Desktop\New -File

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    if ($file.BaseName -notmatch '\S+\s-')
    {
        $newName = $file.Name -replace '^.+?(?=[a-z])'
        $newName = Join-Path $file.DirectoryName $newName

        if (Test-Path -Path $newName)
        {
            Remove-Item -Path $newName
        }
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName $newName

        Write-Verbose $newName
    }
}
```

This will iterate your list and look for your pattern, renaming where necessary.  Assumption: the `source` doesn't have spaces.

Comment: HI, You are correct, the goal of this is to strip out the leading not alpha characters. This is a good example. Just to clarify, the data could be "apache - site1.log" or another server like Tomcat, or .net, or IIS...  not just starting with source... But, I should be able to make this work. thanks for the help!

Comment: Wouldn't `^[^a-z]+` suffice?

Answer (score -1):

1. This might be helpful: [Remove-NonAlphanumericCharFromString](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/12/06/weekend-scripter-remove-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string/).
2. Knowing how to remove non-alphanumeric, take the base name of the file (name without Path and extension).
3. Replace unwanted Chars with empty string.

   ```
   $pattern = '[^a-zA-Z]'
   Set-Location <YourDir>
   Get-Childitem | Foreach-Object {
       Rename-Item -Path ".\$($_.Name)" -NewName "$($_.BaseName -replace $pattern,'')$($_.extension)"
   }
   ```
4. Note that above will fail upon a need to overwrite existing file.

Comment: Your suggestion would remove *all* non-alphabet characters from the basename, changing `1. source - data (1).log` to `sourcedata.log` instead of the desired `source - data (1).log`. Also, `-replace` is case-insensitive by default, so `[^a-zA-Z]` is redundant.